# How can I convert object type into int?

Tags: list, object, types

How can I convert location feature from object type to int?

For example :
location = ("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Algeria"...)

To

Afghanistan :0
Angola :1
Algeria: 2

Comment: using a so called  `enumeration`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get your question properly but I assume that you are working on python.

let's keep it very simple.

**code**

```
m_tuple = ("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Algeria")
m_dict = {m_tuple[n]: n for n in range(len(m_tuple))}  
for key, value in m_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

**output**

```
Afghanistan 0
Angola 1
Algeria 2
```

Default you have tuple, need to convert into python dictionary that will easily accessible by key and values.